# How to select certain class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dom

Here's the problem; I have a couple of divs like the one below, same class name, no id. I need to modify the `<span>` text below the `<h4>` tag, based on where's the mouse cursor on those 3 images. I do this using javascript, by using `mouseenter()` method. The problem is that the method changes every span text from whole web page, not only from the class with class name "parent" where the mouse cursor is at the moment.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="parent.child">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <div class="parent.chil.child">
          <div class="parent.chil.child.child">
               <img src ="link1" data-price="a">
               <img src ="link2" data-price="b">
               <img src ="link3" data-price="c">
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <h4>
      <a href= "aspPage.aspx">text</a>
   </h4>
   <p><span class = "spanClassName">text to be changed</span>some text</p>
   <div class=child1"></div>
</div>
```

How do I select  only the link where's the mouse, from the curent "parent" div, even if there are several div with same class name, "parent".

I hope I was understood, if not, please ask and I try to explain more.

Comment: You would do this same way you would with CSS. So $('.parent > span.SpanClassName').mouseenter();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent with `.parent` class

```
$('.parent\\.chil\\.child\\.child img').on('hover', function(){
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.spanClassName').text($(this).attr('data-price'))
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7JQQ8/)

Additionally as per [**documents**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you need to escape `.` in your selectors

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: This seems to be the closest solution for my problem at the moment. I will try to implement it tomorrow when I get back to work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It's working. I only needed this part : [code]$(this).closest('.parent').find('.spanClassName')...[/code]. Didn't know how to find the DOM node I wanted. Thank you Satpal, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the specific parent node, just use `parent.find('.spanClassName')`. If you don't have the parent node, but you know which link the mouse is on, you can use `link.closest('.parent').find('.spanClassName')`.